# Reading cookies from server from another domain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, rest, cookies

I have a UI in AngularJS making calls to REST webservice in Java. Both are deployed on different domains. The webservice and AngularJS both have CORS enabled.

The webservice returns a cookie as part of one REST request. The cookie has the webservice domain in it.

In my AngularJS app, I will be making that REST request to the server and then have to read that cookie returned as response.

How can I read the cookie returned back from that webservice?
I have read that I cannot access the cookies which are from different domain. I have not exactly understood how does this actually work.

Another question is that if I cannot read the cookie, then can I set cookie from AngularJS app for that domain and that will be sent across to the webservice?

Answer (score 7):

You can't access cookies from another domain via JS, and may not be able to access them at all from JS depending on the properties of the cookie. **This is all enforced by the browser.**

If you are using an API hosted on another domain, **then you might consider [using tokens](http://jwt.io/) and [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), and then using an [HttpInterceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)** to add the security token to your headers when making calls.

**If your security infrastructure depends on you having cookies**, then you are going to have to use some kind of shared token that can be exchanged for a cookie on both domains.