# AngularJs: Can not read cookies sent from server

Tags: java, angularjs, cookies, jersey, jersey-2.0

I've browsed a bunch of questions that are similar to mine, but none of the solutions I have tried seem to work.

I have a Jersey2.0 REST service that adds a cookie to the response and returns it to an Angularjs front end application. I already have the setup done correctly (Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true, no wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin, etc..).

I do it by adding a "SET-COOKIE" header on the response like so:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
headers.add("SET-COOKIE", new NewCookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
```

This works, and I can see the cookie being returned in the response of that particular REST service call to that particular REST endpoint. What I mean is, on the Chrome developer console under the Network tab, I can click on the request that is supposed to return the cookie, and in both the 'Cookies' and 'Headers' tabs, I can see the cookie being returned in the response. In fact, when I make another request to the endpoint, that same cookie is now sent in the request and I can capture it on the Jersey server.

Great. The issue is that the cookie is not showing up on the 'Resources' tab. If I click on the 'Resources' tab, then along the left select the 'Cookies' dropdown and then select localhost, the cookie I'm trying to send in the response is not there. I'm assuming this is also why when I try to get the cookie in my AngularJs application via `$cookies.get('cookieId');` using ngCookies, I get undefined.

Also, just in case someone mentions it in an answer/comments, I'm pretty sure the problem here is not HttpOnly. My JSESSIONID cookie gets returned, and I can see it in the 'Resources' tab with the Http field checked indicating HttpOnly.

I thought maybe because I'm in a corporate environment, they don't let me add cookies, but I'm able to do this on the Angular front end via `$Cookies.put('cookieId', 'cookieValue');` and it shows on the 'Resources' tab just fine.

Any help as to why my cookies are not being added from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through a few more stackoverflow questions relating to my original one, I found out through [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783786/reading-cookies-from-server-from-another-domain) that cookies that are created on one domain cannot be accessed on another domain using Javascript.

I will have to come up with a workaround for this, but my original question has been answered so marking this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

For your case it is easy to solve if you just set the path of the cookie,
e.g.

```
Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("Name_of_cookie", "String_value_of_cookie")
myCookie.setPath("/the domain Js is using ")
```

Or just leave it as `/` for the main domain that most probably Js is deployed.